# Incorrectly awarded the synonymizer badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms, tag-deletion

This weekend I received the synonymizer badge for [flashcs5](/questions/tagged/flashcs5) -> [flash-cs5](/questions/tagged/flash-cs5).  While I am very happy about this, I fear it may have been awarded in error.

I set up the synonym suggestion for this several months ago, and a couple of weeks ago I decided to check on its progress.  I discovered that I had gained no support at all. I also saw that [flashcs5](/questions/tagged/flashcs5) had only twenty-something questions attached to it, and so decided to simply re-tag those questions with the correct tag and let [flashcs5](/questions/tagged/flashcs5) quietly die.  What seems to have happened is that instead of burninating, it has become a synonym without having to have the usual required community support.

Naturally if this is the desired behaviour (or if a mod has silently intervened) then I shall happily continue to sport my shiny new badge, but it did make me wonder if a false synonym could be created by following these steps:

1. Create a question with a new tag
2. Suggest the new tag as an inappropriate synonym
3. Delete the previously created question

I've not tried this myself as it seems to take several days for any effect to be seen, and I didn't want to generate noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What seems to have happened is that instead of burninating, it has become a synonym without having to have the usual required community support.

Perhaps it seems that way, cause my UI kind of sucks however I can assure you that [Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev), a moderator on Stack Overflow, approved this synonym on the 14th of Jan 2012.

Moderators have binding votes.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't expect it because I thought that by taking all the tag's questions it would have been destroyed. Could someone maybe have used it again after I did all the re-tagging?